# .Net Core Web API: Persisting data without Databases

Tags: c#, .net, api

I'm implementing a .Net Core Web API, and I need to store data (specifically, a object that has a List and 3 Queue objects as attributes.
This project is for demonstration only, so i'm not inclined to build a database for it. I need receive and persist data from the post and put API controller methods in this object's queues and lists, and present them later when there's a GET requisition.
I've tried setting it up as a singleton in Startup's ConfigureServices method, and using dependency injection on the controller, but it didn't work.
I'm open to any easy ideas to persist this and showcase the API itself. The data, best practices, etc don't matter that much at this point.

Comment: "I've tried setting it up as a singleton in Startup's ConfigureServices method, and using dependency injection on the controller, `but it didn't work.`" -- That's interesting.. you should post your code. Because it should work just fine.

Comment: I got it to work now. Only worked once I defined an interface for the singleton class and passed the interface as an argument to the controller's constructor, then set it up as a class variable. After that, it is flawless.

Comment: Sounds good -- That's how it should be done. You are on the right track. Also, take a look at `services.AddMemoryCache()` if you need a cache to test with. You end up injecting `IMemoryCache` service.